# Java Mail not working

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail

I am sending an email using the Java mail api. And it works fine when I send an email to myself from my own account. But when I try to send an email to a different account it gives me an authentication exception. Here is my code:

```
package nl.cofely.MailHandler;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

public class Mail extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
private String _user;
private String[] _to;
private String _from;
private String _pass;

private String _port;
private String _sport;

private String _host;

private String _subject;
private String _body;

private boolean _auth;

private boolean _debuggable;

private boolean testMessageSend;

private Multipart _multipart;
static Mail instance;

private Mail() {
    _host = "smtp.gmail.com"; // default smtp server
    _port = "465"; // default smtp port
    _sport = "465"; // default socketfactory port

    _subject = "Person in trouble   !"; // email subject
    _body = ""; // email body

    _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
    _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

    _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

    // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a
    // handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap
            .getDefaultCommandMap();
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
}
public static Mail getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
        instance = new Mail();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void addAttachment(String filename) throws Exception {
    BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
    messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
    messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

    _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
}

@Override
public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication(_user, _pass);
}

private Properties _setProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();

    props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

    if (_debuggable) {
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    }

    if (_auth) {
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    }

    props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", _sport);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

    return props;
}

// the getters and setters
public String getBody() {
    return _body;
}

public void setBody(String _body) {
    _body = _body + " gebruiker: " + _from;
    this._body = _body;
}

// more of the getters and setters …..
public boolean send() throws Exception {
    Properties props = _setProperties();

    if (!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0
            && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("")
            && !_body.equals("")) {
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, this);

        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

        InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
            addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
        }
        msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

        msg.setSubject(_subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());

        // setup message body
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
        if(testMessageSend){
            _multipart.removeBodyPart(0);
        }
        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart,0);
        System.out.println(_multipart.getBodyPart(0));

        // Put parts in message
        msg.setContent(_multipart);


        // send email
        Transport.send(msg);

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public boolean sendTestMail() throws Exception{
    setSubject("Testing mail configuration!");
    setBody("Dit is een email voor het testen van de email configuratie ");
    testMessageSend = send();
    setBody("");
    return testMessageSend;
}
public void setFrom(String _from){
    this._from = _from;
}
public String getFrom(){
    return _from;
}
public void setPass(String _pass){
    this._pass = _pass;
}
public String getPass(){
    return _pass;
}
public void setSubject(String _subject){
    this._subject = _subject;
}
public String getSubject(){
    return _subject;
}
public void setUser(String _user){
    this._user = _user;
}
public String getUser(){
    return _user;
}

public void updateUserInfo(String[] _to, String _from, String _pass){
    this._to = _to;
    this._from = _from;
    this._pass = _pass;
    this._user = _to[0].substring(0, _to[0].lastIndexOf("@"));
}
```

}

Can anyone tell what is going on here? Thanks

Comment: This works for you in Android...?

Comment: Yeah, at least when sending an email to myself

Comment: Well, I don't get any Syntax errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public int sendMail(String reciever_email, String subject, String body) {
    final String username = "YOUR USER EMAIL";
    final String password = "PASSWORD";
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.user", username);
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.EnableSSL.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallbac k", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
        }
    });

    try {
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(reciever_email));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setText(body);
        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
        BodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent("<html>HELLO</html>", "text/html");

        multipart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
        message.setContent(multipart);
        Transport.send(message);
        return 1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the above code includes a few of these [common JavaMail mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).  It also includes improper capitalization on some of the properties, which means they're just being ignored.  If you're trying to use Gmail, [here's the simple way to do it](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).